# How Do I Use this data provided by Rapid API in php in my code?

Tags: php, api

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/search?number=10&offset=0&query=burger",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "__PRIVATE_KEY__",
    "X-Mashape-Host" => "__REMOTE_HOST__"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to download unirest-php php library From this link   https://github.com/Kong/unirest-php

Then next create php script and add unirest

```
<?php 
require_once 'unirest-php/src/Unirest.php';   // here we add path of Unirest.php 

$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/search?number=10&offset=0&query=burger",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "privatekey",
    "X-Mashape-Host" => "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com"
  )
);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($response);
 ?>
```

When we run this code then we get following proper output in response

[image]

Now it's works perfectly

**Happy Programming**

Thanks,
AS