# Fetching data from external API RapidApi to Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, rapidapi

I am trying to fetch data from this API:

```
https://rapidapi.com/apilayernet/api/rest-countries-v1? 
endpoint=53aa5a08e4b0a705fcc323a6
```

I managed to use wp_remote_get() to make the request but I keep getting no result showing up apart from an error:

```
 The site is experiencing technical difficulties.
```

I just point out thatI have used Composer to set up the Composer.json file in my XAMPP proper folder in which I have included the request:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "mashape/unirest-php": "3.*"
    }
}
```

In my code I am including the parameter for the API key as below but for some reason is not working:

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/all', 
array(
"X-RapidAPI-Host" => "restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
"X-RapidAPI-Key" => "7fc872eb0bmsh1baf0c288235a1ep114aecjsn18f888f020c0"
 ) );
 if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
return false; // Bail early
}
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = json_decode( $body );
echo $data;
```

Comment: The example from the docs use POST request, try changing to `wp_remote_post()` method  instead of `wp_remote_get()`

Comment: This is my understanding: POST is for adding data to the Database of the external API but in my case I want to do retrieve data from the APIand I think I should use GET? I tried also with POST to see what happens and still same result. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_remote_get` accepts an array of options as the second argument, but you passed the headers directly.
They should be inside a nested `headers` array inside the options.

Method Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

```
$request = wp_remote_get('https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/all', [
    'headers' => [
        'X-RapidAPI-Host' => 'restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key' => '<apikey>',
    ],
]);

if (is_wp_error($request)) {
    return false; // Bail early
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
$data = json_decode($body);
echo $data;
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use on all of my gets from Wordpress

```
$url = 'https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/all'; //define url
$response = wp_remote_get($url, array(
       'headers'=> array('X-RapidAPI-Host' => 'restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com', //set header
                         'X-RapidAPI-Key' => '<apikey>'//set api key
                          ),
        'method'      => 'GET',//set method
        ));

 $decode = json_decode($response);// decode response
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($decode); die('dead');// display response on page wiothout any other information.
```

Comment: Yes thanks you for the kind reply. For other readers, I got the answer to my issue from another similar question even if not wp related it works on wp as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281830/how-do-i-use-this-data-provided-by-rapid-api-in-php-in-my-code